# Viewing IFRAME independent of whether using HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: html, http, url, iframe, https

Let's say I have the following IFRAME.  It works fine as long as the browser is viewing the page using HTTP, however, if the browser is viewing the page using HTTPS, it will result in errors, and the IFRAME must be changed to also use HTTPS.

```
<iframe id="sitePreview" name="sitePreview" src="http://preview.administrator.test6.example.com/index.php?cid=17&amp;preview=1330668404"></iframe>
```

Without using server script to customize the protocol of the HTML based on the protocol being used to view the page, is it possible to create the URI so that they will work with both HTTP and HTTPS?

Also, please comment if this applies to other links such as:

```
<img alt="Map" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:blue|31 Milk St Boston MA&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=400x400&amp;sensor=false" class="map">

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind cross site iframe calls can be tricky, read this article:
http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/, however, since it does load, I'm assuming you are including an iframe from the same domain.

To answer your question, simply drop the protocol off the src, you would reference it as:

```
<iframe id="sitePreview" name="sitePreview" src="//preview.administrator.test6.example.com/index.php?cid=17&amp;preview=1330668404"></iframe>
```

This will make sure that it will use whatever protocol the parent is using...

You could also hardcode it to https, but that would mean that every request will serve a secure image which creates unnecessary overhead...

Comment: Thanks HappyHamburger.  What if the iframe (or other type of link) was to a different domain?

Comment: Have a look at postMessage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:
    If(location == "https://whatever.com")
    {
    //this is https
    }
    Else
    {
    //it's http
    }

Let me know if I didn't get it right and I will recode it.

Comment: Where your proposed script is running serverside (PHP, etc)?

Comment: It's javascript so it should run on the page where you need to know if it's http or https. In my code in the if statement you can add the code you need. So you can add document.write to each if and echo out the correct iframe. Hope this helps I am on the phone so I made my answer short.